# How can I hide my data folder in Android?

Tags: android

Is there are way to hide my application's data folder in Android? I'm storing some stuff in sdcard/data/{package name} and I would like it to be private.

Thanks.

**Update**
Sorry, I meant the internal memory. I'll be using it to cache some images.

Comment: Why?  If I want to look at the files you are storing on my SD card I should be able to.  Your app does not own my device.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the internal memory. I'm basically using it as a cache, and users have the option to empty the data stored there. I know that IMDb does something similar to this.

Comment: @ Ed S.: I agree in principle but I can think of a couple of valid cases. 1. The users themselves may want personal information to be stored 'securely'. 2. A pro app dev may be storing app resources that he/she doesn't want to be accessible to competing app devs, i.e., copyright data. In either case, of course, hiding stuff in a file system isn't going to be enough and more likely just a deterrent or extra hurdle to get over. That said, I don't think the OP's question is unreasonable.

Comment: To clearify this some more: You want these files basically protected from the "clear cache" function that android os provides (because these are basically hidden (as in non-readable), so the term *hide* confuses me a bit here)?

Comment: @Michell: in light of your comment - the internal storage is private by default at an app-specific level but a 'rooted' phone can bypass that. In this case, encryption is still the best approach.

Comment: @alextsc No, I just want to make sure that a user doesn't delete the files by mistake. I've got nothing to hide, just don't want them deleted unless the user is aware of what he/she is doing.

Comment: @MisterQuonk Thanks, I am using a rooted device myself, and the folder does show up when using a file manager, but other folders in the data folder don't appear unless I'm using the File Explorer in the Android SDK when connected to my device. That's why I wanted to know what I could do to make my data like the other folders.

Comment: @Michell Bak - please explain what you mean about this folder showing up differently that others in a file manager.  Normally the /data folder is not listable by a non-root file manager or non-root adb/ddms session, and a root file manager should be able to list all folders.  With world-readable permission, something layers below /data could be accessible by a non-root file manager, but you'd have to directly enter its path, since you can't browse the intermediate directories to get there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. It seems I just created a folder in the data folder that was readable by all (world readable permission, I suspect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the android security model is intact, files in your application's private storage area are only visible to your application and any other applications you have signed and assigned to share it's userid, unless you set them with world readable permission.

However, you cannot rely on this because there are a significant number of devices out there where the original security model is not intact: including development devices and emulators without it turned on, devices where the model is invalidated by bugs, or devices owned by end users who have customized (ie, "rooted") the device.  In these cases the application's private files will be accessible to the end user, and likely also to some add-on tools and applications on the device.