# Is it possible to hide Android app storage from the user?

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-storage

I am building an Android app and I want to hide some files in the storage from the user. In our app the user can read pdf-magazines but the user isn't allowed to share this pdf's with other people.
Is this possible in Java/Android?

Comment: Use getFilesDir(). And how did those files land on the device?

Comment: When you connect your device to a computer you can access the app storage of this device. So I looking to find a solution that when I do this, I can't see the PDF

Comment: I think that this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277254/how-can-i-hide-my-data-folder-in-android.  Short version: if the user 'root's his device, all bets are off.

Comment: `When you connect your device to a computer you can access the app storage of this device` Yes. Every device has several storage locations. And getFilesDir() will not be shown then.